# JMeter count controllers

Tags: java, controller, jmeter

I have a JMeter script in which I want to count how many controllers there are in a thread. I want to count them before I run through them. I know if I run through them I can count them one by one with beanshell but I want to count them before I enter the thread or at the start of the thread above the controllers.

Comment: what exact contollers are you interested in?

Comment: Throughput controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) somewhere and use the following code in order to determine the Throughput Controllers count:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Collection;

StandardJMeterEngine engine = ctx.getEngine();
Field test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
test.setAccessible(true);
HashTree testPlanTree = (HashTree) test.get(engine);

SearchByClass throughputControllersSearch = new SearchByClass(ThroughputController.class);
testPlanTree.traverse(throughputControllersSearch);
Collection throughputControllers = throughputControllersSearch.getSearchResults();
log.info("Found " + throughputControllers.size() + " throughput controllers in the test plan");
```

Demo:

[image: Beanshell Sampler]

References:

- `ctx` - stands for [JMeterContextService](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html)
- [HashTree](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html) and [SearchByClass](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/SearchByClass.html) are [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/overview-summary.html) classes
- others are core Java

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter tests along with few examples